# Is all entropy calculation an estimation in practice?

Tags: entropy

Self information is defined by the $-\log$ the probability. However, how do we know the probability distribution in the first place? (Same goes for Shannon Entropy)

Does this mean that in practice all entropy calculations are estimations?